# Will the GorillaPod SLR-Zoom keep my DSLR camera from falling over/off?

Tags: dslr, tripod, gorillapod

I have a DSLR and a lens and am considering buying a GorillaPod for when I'm out and about and can find surfaces to place it on/attach it to.

My main concern is whether I can rely on it to keep my camera/lens in place -- it is a scary prospect just wrapping the legs around a pole or a tree and then hoping that my camera doesn't fall off (and that the GorillaPod doesn't slip down and cause the camera to fall.)

Is the GorillaPod SLR-Zoom a trustworthy option?

Comment: Any particular lens you're wanting to use with it?  There's a considerable difference if you're wanting to use a 50mm vs a 400mm.

Comment: I had in mind a 50mm or a small kit lens. I guess I want answers to include any relevant info about camera/lens combos that weigh under the 3 kg limit that the GorillaPod SLR/Zoom can handle but maybe with a 400mm lens there would be centre of mass issues too?

Comment: It works better wrapped around something than just sitting on a table top.  It probably would have centre of mass issues with a heavy lens if used like a conventional tripod.

Comment: As an aside, it's worth getting the ball head for the GorillaPod. If you don't then you'll find it awkward to position the camera so that it's level (trust me!).

Comment: Sitting on a tabletop, it definitely has the center of mass issues @MikeW predicts with anything heavier or longer than a kit zoom or small prime.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine for a railing or something you can really wrap it around well.  Something like a tree trunk or large vertical pole, not so much.  It's well built, the camera wouldn't fall off, but it could slip down if there's not much friction to hold it in place.

Edit: the GorillaPod SLR-Zoom is rated at 3kg (6.5 lbs).  My D90, which is a heavy camera, with an 18-200 VR, also heavy, totals under 1.5kg (3 lbs).

Answer (score 2):

I have used the GorillaPod SLR (the one below the SLR zoom, so lower capacity) with my Canon EOS 550D + 18-55mm IS kit lens, and had no issues with stability (less than a kg combined). My GorillaPod is almost 5 years old now, but still going strong.

I also have the 55-250mm IS lens, but haven't used it with the GorillaPod yet. The main concern I see when using a longer\heavier lens is the camera becoming front heavy, particularly with the amateur DSLRs (Canon xxxxD\xxxD; Nikon D3xxx\D5xxx), & I'm not sure whether a lens tripod mount would improve the situation (or even work with the GorillaPod) in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I entrusted my DSLR to one when attaching it to street sign posts and a 19th storey balcony railing when I was on holiday a while back. It didn't give me any concerns about the legs slipping although I was careful to have the strap looped around my arm when mounting and dismounting the gorillapod.

-edit: This was using the kit 18-55 lens, not heavy at all, but there was room in its holding power for something heavier.